batch add category to list of pages or files
I am using pywikibot 9.3.1, MediaWiki 1.42
I can add a category to a list of files in my mediawiki installation with the category script:
pwb category add -file:e:/in.txt -to:Bibliothek
after each entry the script asks the following:
Edit summary: Bot: Ergänze Kategorie [[:Category:Bibliothek|Bibliothek]]
Do you want to accept these changes? ([y]es, [N]o, [a]ll, [q]uit):
How can I get the script to accept each entry in my file list without asking for confirmation? I tried the parameter -always, but that has no effect.
There is also a paramter -batch, which has no effect either.
Is there a way to run the category script in batch mode, without any user input?
